# What is del and how to find its version?

Tags: npm, gulp

I copied and pasted code from somewhere to my `package.json`. And I believe that I installed gulp.js already. Now I have:

```
{
  "name": "ProjectNameHere",
  "version": "Major.Minor.Patch",
  "dependencies": {
    "gulp": "^3.8.11",
    "gulp-dotnet-assembly-info": "^0.1.10",
    "gulp-msbuild": "^0.2.9",
    "gulp-xunit-runner": "^0.1.1",
    "nuget-runner": "^0.1.5",
    "xmlpoke": "^0.1.9",
    "yargs": "^3.8.0",
    "del": "^1.1.1",
    "bower": "1.4.1" // only if you're in a web project
  }
}
```

My question is what is `"del": "^1.1.1"` and how can I verify it is `1.1.1`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search on [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/). It turns out that [`del`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/del) is used to "delete files/folders using globs."

The latest release is [v2.0.2](https://github.com/sindresorhus/del/tree/v2.0.2) from just over a week ago; [v1.1.1](https://github.com/sindresorhus/del/tree/v1.1.1) was authored 12/25/2014.

---

### Usage

```
var del = require('del');

del(['tmp/*.js', '!tmp/unicorn.js']).then(function (paths) {
    console.log('Deleted files/folders:\n', paths.join('\n'));
});
```

Comment: How can I verify the `del` version in my machine? I am not sure it is `v2.0.2` or `v1.1.1`. As I need to put it in my package.json file.

Comment: @Love if you installed your packages using the `package.json` it should be v1.1.1, but feel free to check in the CLI with `npm view del version`.

Comment: Okay, I used the command and found it is `v2.0.2`. I manually typed the package.json file by notepad++. So can we also find others versions in my sample package.json file?

Comment: Use `npm install` to install everything from your `package.json`.

Comment: `npm ls del` will display all instances of `del` in your `node_modules/` directory plus each of their versions. `npm view del` would show you the registry's latest metadata for `del`.